# SELECT to get data vs storing it in a field?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite, select, complexity-theory

**A little bit of back story: (skip down below to bold to just get to the question)**

I've been programming in Python the past few months, but I am still very much a beginner. I know the basics (loops, if statements, functions, classes, etc), but lack the finer knowledge (big-o notation, how indexes work, etc).

I've got a sqlite database that I've been storing data into for a project. In one table, called papers, each row consists of a paper I've written, along with the class it was for, the category (technology, fiction, whitepaper, etc), and the rating associated with it (1-5).

So my table looks something like:

```
PID|                Paper Name       |        Class      |     Category          |  Rating

 1 | A Foo Bar Story: The study of X |   Intro to Foobar |  Term Paper, Science  |  4
```

...(etc)

I also created another table called Classes, which looks similar to this

```
Class Name | ClassURL | Teacher Email | Ratings | Vote count

Intro to Foobar | www.foobar.com/itf | xyz@zyx.com | 240 | 100
```

...(etc)

Where the class rating is the ratings divided by the vote count.

**My question is this**:
Right now, I currently just update the ratings field and the vote-count field whenever I rate a paper by adding that rating for the paper into "ratings" and adding one to "vote count" using `UPDATE classes SET ratings=(?), vote_count=(?) where classname=(?)` (with the variables).
At the time I thought it would be less complexity than to do a `SELECT` of all the papers in the paper table (which, lets just assume could be limitless) `WHERE class= "Whatever"`, then adding them all up and then dividing them by the count. The more I think about it however, though, the more unsure I am. Could someone point me as to which one would be quicker over a large database of papers, and why?

Comment: i'm still unclear on what you're trying to achieve.  are you ultimately trying to come up with some kind of average rating?  it seems like your best bet is to not store the calculated data (e.g. vote count) and instead periodically run queries when you need to total things up.  what you probably want to do is something like: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Papers WHERE Class = 'ClassNameHere' (to get the number of votes

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should avoid to store redundant data. Sooner or later someone or something will mess it up so that your data gets out of sync, which will cause you a lot of pain.

You can easily calculate the class ratings by using SUM and COUNT, e.g. (not tested!)

```
SELECT ClassName, SUM(Rating)/COUNT(*) FROM Papers GROUP BY ClassName
```

That is, you do not have to do the calculations in the client, your database can easily do that.

You should drop the redundant columns Classes.Ratings and Classes.Votecount unless you have a **really** good reason to keep them. I think a SELECT involving class ratings might be a little bit faster if you keep the redundant columns, esp. if you want to have the class rating along with other attributes of the class like teacher email. But this is completely irrelevant unless you have, say, a really large database queried by a website with really high traffic, which I doubt.

If you care about speed, keeping redundant columns is definitely **not** the first step to take. I am not sure how sqlite handles indexing - in MySQL, you would make sure that the table Papers has an index for the column ClassName to speed up the query above. If you are running complex queries (which, btw., the above one is not), start optimizing your queries first.